# schedule django custom commands with cron inside a virtualenvironment

Tags: python, django, cron, virtualenv

I have written a custom management command `post_message` when I run `python manage.py post_message` the command executes well.

Now I want this command to run every 10 minutes.

I have a virtual envrironment.

I have a file - msg.cron the contents of the file are as follows -

```
#!SHELL=/bin/bash
*/10 * * * * source /home/username/Envs/project_name/bin/activate && /home/username/Code/project_name/manage.py post_message > /dev/null
```

I have done chmod +x on msg.cron

Having done this, I added

```
crontab msg.cron
```

Now when I do `crontab -l` contents of msg.cron are shown.

But the management command are not being run, what am I missing?

Comment: try without `source`, making sure the `activate` and `manage.py` are executable (and the first line is `#!<path to interpreter>`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to activate the virtualenv in this case. You can just use the python in the bin directory of the virtualenv.

```
*/10 * * * * source /home/username/Envs/project_name/bin/python /home/username/Code/project_name/manage.py post_message > /dev/null
```